# How to get access to <class bpy_prop_array> via bpy?

Tags: python, properties

For my script I need to recursively iterate through bpy hierarchy and check if attributes suit several conditions. One of those conditions is if the attribute is an instance of the `<class bpy_prop_array>`, e.g. object Bounding Box. It can be done with Python embedded `isinstance()` method, but I need an access to the class itself. How can I get access to `bpy_prop_array` class? Where is it situated and how can it be imported to the script for this purpose? Or maybe there is some other way to check this condition?

I searched in `bpy.types`, in `mathutils`, in `bpy_extras` subclasses but could not find anything relative.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it. To use `bpy_prop_array` in the code first we need to:

```
from bpy_types import bpy_types
```

and after that it can be found in `bpy_types.bpy_prop_array`